# Properly structure an existing project into the MVC architecture

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm taking a legacy classic asp project up to more modern technology (I've been working with ASP.NET MVC lately so using this concept is stuck in my mind), but I'm trying to think of how to structure the project.

The idea is that the company provides a service to clients, but the service is housed on the company's website (instead of the client's) and has some branding/specifics to the client. Let's say there are 4 or 5 pages/steps for the service, but a few of those pages/steps can be customized for each client. So, what I'd prefer is:

`*/step1`

`*/step2`

`*/step3`

`*/step4`

`*/step5`

Where `*` is the `client` name but the steps are reusable. This doesn't seem to lend itself to the standard MVC structure, or I can't seem to see the forest for the trees. I wouldn't want a controller for each `client` and repeat the steps for `n` clients. I'd rather have 5 steps where `step2` or `step3` could be expanded upon for client X, expanded upon more for client Y and left alone for client Z.

If the company has 100 clients that want the standard 5 steps (no customization), you wouldn't want 100 controllers serving up 5 steps (500 `.cshtml` pages in the project)...right? How would one design this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would tackle this problem is by using a ControllerFactory to create the appropriate controller based on both the step and client and hand-off the further processing to that controller.

The controller hierarchy would look like this:

```
BaseController
|
+-- Step1Controller
|
+-- Step2Controller
|   |
|   +-- Step2ClientXController
|   +-- Step2ClientYController
|
+-- Step3Controller
|   |
|   +-- Step3ClientXController
|   +-- Step3ClientZController
|
+-- Step4Controller
|
+-- Step5Controller
```

Comment: So, in this scenario, the `Step2Controller` would be used for clients who do not expand upon step2 and `Step2ClientXController` would be used for ClientX who wanted to expand upon it? But then these would render `Step2.cshtml` and `Step2ClientX.cshtml`?

Comment: @ethorn10: Yes, but it would depend on the kind of customization that is done for Client X if the Client X specific controller re-uses the generic view or if there is also a customized view.